# Thunderbird : Load remote images when going to offline mode

Tags: email, thunderbird

I already know I can change "mailnews.message_display.disable_remote_image" to false on config options for evade. The question is about loading remote images. If thunderbird downloads messages when going offline, it does it without remote images. It only loads remote images when the user looks at the email directly. How I can force it to download emails with remote images when going offline? Is it possible?

Comment: There is no way for Thunderbird to download remote images before going offline as the remote images will not appear when you restart the Thunderbird and work offline. The remote images need to load everytime and you must be online. This is because Thunderbird developer team did not include such features in Thunderbird.